# Can an Android service update image in my UI

Tags: service, android

I would like to have an Android service that collects data and then produces images based on that data. I would like to draw this image on my UI from within the service or find an efficient way to send the image data to my UI with a notification to "draw it now". The data are coming in real-time and the update rate is about 8 images a second (256x256 pixels). Thus, I need something fairly efficient and am having a hard time finding the best (or even a good) method for doing this.

I'm a fairly new Android programmer so no advice is too insulting! I have my code working as an AsyncTask with my demo UI.  I would like to turn this into a service so I can use it with multiple UIs, some of which my colleagues will be writing. Maybe that's another question, but it could be there is a better way to do this than a service. My fundamental problem is that I'd like to distribute my "service" without source code to my colleagues for their use to allow my images to be displayed in their UIs.

My "service" does NOT have to update multiple UIs. Only one activity will bind to my "service" at a time. No requirement for broadcasting to multiple activities. If there is a more straightforward way to think about this, I'm happy to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write your data to a file. store it on the sd-card. And then send to your friends activity a broadcast with the data about the file. This way your friends wont have the source code.

Comment: Seems this would be too slow and I will probably need to update the image at a time when the UI is trying to display it. File permission issues will ensue...

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to draw this image on my UI from within the service or find an efficient way to send the image data to my UI with a notification to "draw it now".

you cannot do that -- only main thread can change UI.  i bet in your AsyncTask demo you draw inside onPostExecute() method -- try moving your code to doInBackground(), it wont work.

i think best you can do is to fetch/acquire image inside your service and inform your consumers using broadcast/otto/whatever that it's somewhere on sd card and it can be used. not quite sure if it will be fast enough to pass 8 images per second...

Comment: Actually, I do use doInBackground and then publishProgress() when I've created a new bitmap. Works great. I'm looking to do the same but using a service. I think writing to the SD card would work, but will be too slow and has other issues (like overwriting it while someone else is reading it, which I need to be able to do).

I guess what I'm really looking for is an efficient shared memory resource for Android. Is there such a thing? Then my service can simply notify the UI that a new image is ready and the UI can grab it when it wants.